# App Screen Density Support for Play Store

Tags: android, xml, google-play, android-manifest, screen-density

I want to deploy my App in Play Store for small and normal Handsets of all densities.
The `android:screenDensity` attribute of `<screen>` element does not have `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` densities as predefined values.
Should I use the values `480` and `560` for the corresponding missing densities?

Or could I use this?

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Does this cover all the densities of the selected screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

In the `<supports-screens>` tag, setting the values of `android:largeScreens` and `android:xlargeScreens` to false would not make your app unavailable for these screen sizes. It will just enable screen compatibility mode for your app on these screen sizes.

From Android Developer [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html):

**android:largeScreens**

> Indicates whether the application supports larger screen form-factors. A large screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "normal" handset screen, and thus might require some special care on the application's part to make good use of it, though it may rely on resizing by the system to fill the screen.
>   The default value for this actually varies between some versions, so it's better if you explicitly declare this attribute at all times. Beware that setting it "false" will generally enable screen compatibility mode.

**android:xlargeScreens**

> Indicates whether the application supports extra large screen form-factors. An xlarge screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "large" screen, such as a tablet (or something larger) and may require special care on the application's part to make good use of it, though it may rely on resizing by the system to fill the screen.
>   The default value for this actually varies between some versions, so it's better if you explicitly declare this attribute at all times. Beware that setting it "false" will generally enable screen compatibility mode.

If you want to make your app available only for handsets, add the following to your manifest:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
```

The entries with `android:screenDensity="480"` are to support the xxhdpi buckets.

Take a look at [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) of the Android Developer docs, which explains on how to make your app available to only handsets.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second option; specifying the supported screens and then possibly add anyDensity="true":

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

It shouldn't be necessary to set `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`.
And then always use an emulator to test your app on different screen sizes and densities.